# Uploading BitmapData using Facebook Graph Api

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking around the internet on how to use the PostRequest class given by the Facebook in their Graph Api, but I couldn't find anything on it. I'm wondering how to use it to upload a bitmapdata. It just doesn't seem to be moving at all.

I used this code and it worked:

```
private function getSnapshot(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    bmd = new BitmapData(vidDisplay.width, vidDisplay.height); 
    bmd.draw(vidDisplay);
    vidDisplay.previewImg.source = new Bitmap(bmd);

    isSnapshot = true;

    vidDisplay.upload_btn.enabled = true;
    vidDisplay.caption_txt.enabled = true;
    vidDisplay.browse_btn.enabled = false;
}

protected function upload(w:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var img:* = (isSnapshot) ? bmd : fileRef ;
    var values:Object = {message:vidDisplay.caption_txt.text, fileName:'FILE_NAME', image:img};

    fb.callApi("post", "me", "photos", values);

    vidDisplay.caption_txt.text = "";
    vidDisplay.upload_btn.enabled = false;
    vidDisplay.snapShot_btn.enabled = false;
}
```

However, when I tried to make a whole function to take a picture and upload straightaway, it doesn't work. At first, it was like this:

```
private function doTakeSnapshot(con:MovieClip, cap:String = null):void
{
    ExternalInterface.call("doAlert", "doTakeSnapshot");

    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(con.width, con.height);
    bmd.draw(con);

    if (cap == null) { cap = "Check out my photo!"; }
    var values:Object = {message:cap, image:bmd};

    doCallApi("post", "me", "photos", values);
}
```

Then I tried with the PostRequest:

```
private function doTakeSnapshot(con:MovieClip, cap:String = null):void
{
    ExternalInterface.call("doAlert", "doTakeSnapshot");

    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(con.width, con.height);
    bmd.draw(con);

    if (cap == null) { cap = "Check out my photo!"; }

    var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);
    var pr:PostRequest = new PostRequest();
    //var ba:ByteArray = pr.getPostData();
    pr.createPostData();
    pr.writePostData("fileName", "testtest");
    pr.writeFileData("fileName", ba, "image/png");
    pr.close();

    var byteArray:ByteArray = pr.getPostData();
    ExternalInterface.call("doAlert", "ByteArray = " + byteArray);

    var values:Object = {message:cap, image:byteArray};

    doCallApi("post", "me", "photos", values);
}
```

Both doesn't work, which puzzles me. The first one worked without encoding it in any way, so I don't get why it doesn't work when I try to just call it like that. Any help?

Comment: Okay, nevermind. I found out the problem already. I forgot to put the fileName:"file_name"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wrap or encode your bitmapdata. Just make a Bitmap and put it in your object like this :

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(con.width, con.height);
bmd.draw(con); 
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bm);
var values:Object = {message:cap, image:bitmap};
fb.callApi("post", "me", "photos", values);
```